# Visual Studios JavaScript Page not calling Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I watch and read a few tutorials on how to run JavaScript in Visual Studios however I am having issues debugging and the code executing. This is what I have done so far.

I see that you can not use the debugger on the HTML file but you can on the JavaScript File.

When I add a break point on the javascript file after the page loads it never hits. The only thing that display when run is the Title on the page. Why does Hello MYName not appear when the page opens.

Visual Studio's 2010 
Visual Basics | Web | ASP.NET Empty Web Application 
Added HTML Page and JavaScript file

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JScript1.js" />

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

alert(hello("MyName"))

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

MY Java Script File

```
function hello(name) {

return "hello " + name;
}
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: why when i launch the page, the only thing that display is the Title Hello. Alert is not being called - should produce Hello MyName

Comment: check if your JS path is proper, you are missing a  semicolon after alert shouldn't matter much but add that.

Comment: Then add that to the question and actually change the title to something that makes sense. Technically the IDE *should* have no effect on the code itself. That said, I'd highly recommend to update to a recent version of VS, as VS 2010 is almost 7 years old...

Comment: @tambre Be less rude..

Comment: editted. - It should work and i pretty much did the same thing as this YOUTube video that did the same thing in the same version of VS https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxHdb2aOAeo

Comment: @CodeMonger did you verify your js file path?

Comment: @Karthik - Not to be funny but what do you mean by verify the file path. Check if it exists? Its part of the project and I referenced it <script type="text/javascript" src="JScript1.js" /> ---- Did I need to specify the whole path?

Comment: I meant to say did you do your project the exact same way as shown in that video or is your js file within any folder? you can press f12 on that function and see if it jumps to the function implementation... apart from that nothing seems to be wrong with your code.. it has to be path or your js file name

Comment: I did it the same exact way as the video

Comment: okay. Thanks I didnt see any issues either. I was really trying to learn how to call a javascript function. This really could have been a hello world program. Was hoping that I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Probably can't find the function. Difficult to tell without seeing your project structure. Change to alert("test") and that will prove if it's hitting.

Comment: do you have any console errors?

Comment: @Jinx88909 - Ah, if i take out <script type="text/javascript" src="JScript1.js" /> and change    alert("test") Test pops up. If I leave <script type="text/javascript" src="JScript1.js" /> alert does not work

Comment: With that said I am not sure why it fails if I have that in...

Comment: It's probably failing to find the JScript1.js file and then not continuing with execution of any other script. Need to verify the path. As it stands the file expects to be in the root of your project (like the video).